# Adafruit ultimate gps breakout module with beaglebone black wireless- UART issue

Tags: c, gps, uart, beagleboneblack, adafruit

I am using the Adafruit Ultimate GPS breakout module to interface with the beaglebone black using c code. I am using UART 4 for that, but while running after compile it won't show any output. I changed the port name to "dev/ttyO4" in serial.h file.
thank you!!!
git hub link for the library: https://github.com/joyalraju/libgps

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gps.h>
int main(void) {
  // Open
  gps_init();
  loc_t data;
  while (1) {
     gps_location(&data);
     printf("%lf %lf\n", data.latitude, data.longitude);
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[image: output figure]

Answer (score 0):

Joyal If you add your code with question make it easy to find out the problem.